If I am using a map as an internal detail, can I declare it only in the source/cpp file?
Context
I have a set of Enums that are auto-generated (copied) from another team's code during project configuration/build. For the curious, the reason is that I work in a simulation environment, and the enums are part of the embedded software that piggy backs off of our simulation. The boss says we can't mingle simulation and ESW code.
Now, I want to create a map of strings to enum values. This map is to be used by a single class, which is defined and instantiated by a factory.
I'm trying to figure out where to put it, and I sorta settled on declaring it inside a detail namespace.
Question
My question is, if it is a detail, not part of any public API, does it still need to be declared in a header file and defined in a cpp file? Or can I keep it from being exported by declaring and defining it inside the cpp file only?
Alternatively, would this be a good place to use an anonymous namespace? Maybe that's a better way to hide this detail?
Motivation
Again for the curious, the reason I want to separate the map from the class definition is to keep things uncluttered. The class definition itself is already nested within the factory's create method, so adding a map with 20 something entries just makes the code ugly. But if that's the best way to go, I'm open to that too.

Don't describe the code, show a [mre].

@3CxEZiVlQ This is a conceptual question about a best practice. It is not specific to any particular application, and therefore does not need a code example to fully describe the question. I recommend thinking before indiscriminately posting the rules, as if every rule always applies in all situations. "a foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of small minds."

does it still need to be declared in a header file In general, no. But sometimes you're forced into it. See PIMPL for an alternative.

Because this question results in fuzzy "Maybe" answers, a concrete example that can be assigned a yes or no answer is highly recommended. No hobgoblins involved.

On the other hand, this question might me more suitable at SO's more abstract companion site [softwareengineering.se].

If I am using a map as an internal detail, can I declare it only in the source/cpp file? Sure. I do that all the time.  Works great.  Less filling.  The more implementation details you can keep out of public header files the better.

Show your concept code.

@user4581301 It seems that I have gotten several unambiguous answers right here in the comments, showing that my question is formed will enough without code to provide actionable insight. While I appreciate the rules, the proof is in the pudding that no code sample was needed.
It may be a better fit for that other site, yes. But I got what I needed here, for which I am grateful.

If the map is only used inside functions and is not part of the functions signature (including parameters and return code) then you only need to put it in the C++ source file.  But if it is in a class and the class members will be called then you will need to use the PIMPL pattern to make the class (one with the public members that call a second implementation class that has the map)

It is good that you have been helped. Jerry's comment above covers the two most likely cases (probably the ONLY two cases, but C++'s ability to surprise me with bizarre edge cases is astounding). In my opinion, you should be able to embed the map in the cpp file, hidden behind the factory and returned by reference and only expose the enum.

"I have gotten several unambiguous answers" - yeah, each of those answers starting with "if ...", and there is no guarantee that you understood them correctly (hopefully yes). It depends on your understanding of "implementation detail" i.e.  std::mapnot only it cannot be part of public methods, it cannot appear anywhere in your (user API) class bodies, because you cannot forward declare it.

And then BAM! my other comment suddenly should be the opposite if I assume that instead of std::map you are using your own internally implemented struct Map. So, I don't agree that following the rules is foolish in this case, it would be way easier to answer with a proper code sample.

I would think that asking "need to be" is not opinion-based. It's not the same as asking if something should be done. (I acknowledge that there are multiple interrogative sentences in the question, some of which drift into subjectivity, but the one identified as "My question is" asks about need.)

@pptaszni "not only it cannot be part of public methods, it cannot appear anywhere in your (user API) class bodies" -- That is the scenario presented by the question. The question says "not part of any public API" and does not refer to "public methods". So your objection looks weak.


does it still need to be declared in a header file

This seems to indicate backwards reasoning. Understandable, but still backwards. Initially, nothing needs to be declared in a header file. It is only when the same declaration is needed in multiple source files that a declaration needs to go into a header file, so that it can be easily shared.
(Since many class definitions do need to be shared, it is common practice to default to defining classes in a header file. It is also common to put complex class definitions in a header file to keep each source file saner. However, this is not the basis for reasoning about where definitions and declarations need to go.)
Even though you might have been told that all declarations go in a header file, it is more accurate to say that all declarations needed by more than one source file go in a header file. If a declaration is not needed by more than one source file, it does not need to go in a header file (barring indirect need, such as being needed by something that is in turn needed by more than one source file). You describe a situation where it seems like a declaration is needed by only one source file. So, no, that declaration does not need – and never needed – to be in a header file.
Rule of thumb: If you can move a fairly simple definition into a source file without breaking compilation, then do it. ("Fairly simple" is to avoid making your source file overly complex.) The compiler will tell you if that was needed somewhere else. Just don't copy to multiple source files. Anonymous namespaces are advised in case of naming conflicts (which the compiler cannot catch, and the linker is unlikely to).

Or can I keep it from being exported by declaring and defining it inside the cpp file only?

Defining something in a source file does not prevent it from being exported, regardless of your definition of "export". You could replace the line #include "header.hpp" with a copy of the contents of header.hpp and not change the result of compiling (until someone changes header.hpp without changing the copy you made, or vice versa). When compiling a single source file, there is no distinction made between "in a header" and "in a source file". The reason for using header files is not to control access, but to keep declarations and definitions in sync across translation units.
If by "export" you mean "available to other source files in my project" (as opposed to "available to users of the library I am building"), then a good strategy is to put the declaration/definition in an anonymous namespace so that it has internal linkage.
